# Resize/scale entire canvas with all objects in fabricjs without loss of quality

Tags: reactjs, canvas, resize, scale, fabricjs

Is there way how to scale/resize entire canvas made in fabric.js ? I have `<canvas className="canvas" ref="canvas" width="895" height="560"></canvas>` then `const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.refs.canvas),`can i change width and height of canvas element and all objects inside ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question has been answered many times.
The best answer on my opinion provided by one of fabricjs contributors Andrea Bogazzi here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019311/3710047

Basically, you can use fabricjs canvas methods:

```
canvas.setZoom(val);
canvas.setWidth(originalWidth * canvas.getZoom());
canvas.setHeight(originalHeight * canvas.getZoom());
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just zoom in on the objects, as opposed to actually scaling them?